# In which property I should return long diagnostic message in the HTTPResponse?

Tags: .net, httpresponse

I return 200 when my service is OK and other code when it is not with the description what is wrong.
I use `HTTPResponse.StatusDescritpion` to put diagnostic info there, however there is length limitation to this property and I cannot return long string.

Which property I should use to return longer message?

Comment: I think you should start by sending the right [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). If you want to send a description of what went wrong, you can return that as the body.

Comment: @rickvdbosch Does `HTTPResponse` have property `Body`? No.

Comment: You can write the body by calling one of the write methods on the [HttpResponse class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse?view=netframework-4.7.2)